# How to completely remove an OS from VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, uninstall

I have installed Windows XP in my VirtualBox some days ago. Now, I want to remove Windows XP completely from VirtualBox and I decided to install Ubuntu 13.04 for testing.

What is the correct way to remove completely Windows XP from VirtualBox?

Answer (score 49):

It makes no sense to keep a particular Virtual Machine and change the OS inside - so remove the VM and create a new one:

#### Virtual Box Manager

In the graphical frontend for Virtual Box we can easily remove a virtual machine by selecting the machine to remove and go to the menu entry *"Machine --> Remove"* or choose *"Remove"* from the right-click context menu.

[image]

We will then be asked whether we wish to only remove the machine (i.e. unregister it) or if we want to also *"Delete all files"*. The latter will completely remove the virtual machine with all files from our drive.

[image]

---

#### Command line

This can also be done from command line with the following command:

```
VBoxManage unregistervm --delete "<Name of Machine>"
```

By doing so the following files will be deleted:

> - all hard disk image files, including differencing files, which are used by the machine and not shared with other machines;
> - saved state files that the machine created, if any (one if the machine was in "saved" state and one for each online snapshot);
> - the machine XML file and its backups;
> - the machine log files, if any;
> - the machine directory, if it is empty after having deleted all the above.

<sup>[Source: Virtual Box Manual](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-registervm)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

If the issue still persists, you can also kill the VBoxHeadless & VirtualBoxVM processes associated with the VM.

E.g. Assume the name of your locked / bad vm is My-Locked-VM.

Get the process id of the VirtualBox processes associated with that VM and kill it.

```
MyHostName:homedir ayekay$ ps -ef| grep -i My-Locked-VM
1624398723  1196 23121   0 11:34AM ??         0:05.11 /Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/Resources/VirtualBoxVM.app/Contents/MacOS/VirtualBoxVM --comment My-Locked-VM --startvm 8dc249f1-6877-4caf-bbd4-27ae6b78ceb6 --no-startvm-errormsgbox --separate
1624398723 89252 23121   0 10:06AM ??         3:07.87 /Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VBoxHeadless --comment My-Locked-VM --startvm 8dc249f1-6877-4caf-bbd4-27ae6b78ceb6 --vrde config
1624398723  2323 79114   0 11:48AM ttys007    0:00.00 grep -i My-Locked-VM
MyHostName:homedir ayekay$ kill -9 1196 89252
MyHostName:homedir ayekay$
```

Once the process is killed, the VirtualBox UI will show the VM state as Aborted. You can then use the UI to delete the VM.

Comment: You could be a bit more elaborate about how to do that, this would greatly improve the quality of your answer.