# How can I erase the RAM which is occupied by Ubuntu in VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, ram

The first time I installed Ubuntu with 2 GB RAM but now it affects my laptop (running slow .. hang) because my laptop has 4 GB RAM. I want to clean the space occupied by Ubuntu in VirtualBox. So how can I delete it from the root?

Comment: The question is unclear. Is Ubuntu installed in VirtualBox? What is the host system? If you don't start the virtual machine, Ubuntu won't use any RAM. Please [edit] your questions and add details. What do you mean by "delete from root"?

Comment: If you shut down Ubuntu in virtual box, and then close virtual box, all the RAM will be released.

Comment: 4GB ram is a bit low trying use virtual box well.  If you want to can try using Lubuntu/Xubuntu and only give it maybe 1GB of ram.  If you take it easy, it might work okay.

Comment: Thank you all I got it

Answer (score 0):

If you create a virtual machine in VirtualBox, you specify the *maximum* amount of RAM it can utilize. The RAM provided to the virtual machine is only occupied when the virtual machine is running. As soon as you stop it, the RAM is released.

If you find the RAM dedicated to a virtual machine is not optimal (either too low for the virtual machine or too little remains for the host OS), you can modify the settings when the virtual machine is not running.

If you want to delete the virtual machine, you can [remove it using the VirtualBox Manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/316177/how-to-completely-remove-an-os-from-virtualbox).